# Fill the user profile properties automatically in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

We want our user profile properties automatically filled from a list what should we do? We do not have complete user information in active directory so we want to use this excel list for fill the user profile properties in order to users do not fill the personal and contact information themselves is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a whole lot of script,

**and** the AD values will still overwrite the Profile values you set, so you need to disable that proces as well

It is best to use PowerShell and fill your AD from that Excel file